# Send mail in Unix issue

Tags: unix

I am trying to send the contents of a file as email in unix.I am using the below code to do this.But when i get the email i see that SUBJECT and TO is blank. Can you please let me know why it is blank? Also the FROM address comes as admin@myhost. Is there any way i can set FROM to user defined value?

```
    SUBJECT="Automated Security Alert"  
    TO="xyz@abc.com"  
    MESSAGE="/export/home/admin/bin/getStatus2.txt"  
    /usr/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE
```

Comment: Most Linux distribution uses mailx for their mailing program, and according to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) you can use `-r` to set from address.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ssmtp from my cygwin to send mails from command line. It is linked with the sendmail command to send mails. I need to configure it only.

For your problem, I guess if you add some alias name in /etc/mail/local-host-names file, probably it will be reflected to the FROM address of the mail in the respective inbox.